# Cisco 877 doesn't respond to IP determined through ARP

Tags: cisco, ip, gateway, arp, packet-capture

I have just obtained an old Cisco 877. I made sure to first push the reset button in the back. I then plugged into one of the LAN ports. The device gave me an IPv4 address (169.254.14.65/16) and an IPv6 address (fe80::9504:ecb9:b0b:e41%38)

I tried sniffing packets using Wireshark, and found that the Cisco device is broadcasting ARP packets. The message is:
    `Who has 192.168.80.1? Tell 192.168.80.9`

My understanding is that 192.168.80.9 should be the address of the Cisco router, yet it doesn't respond to ping or http/https requests.

PS. I am aware that generally to do Cisco config I need to use the console port which requires a console oprt. However I was playing around with trying to access this and was curious. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Cisco 877 didn't give you the `169.254.14.65/16` via DHCP; your computer decided it by itself (using Link-Local Address Selection, [RFC 3927, 2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3927#section-2.1)), because DHCP failed. Possibly the device doesn't have DHCP server enabled. You are currently on a different subnet!

Set your IP address manually to be on the same subnet. If you are correct, that might be `192.168.80.0/24`, but factory reseted Cisco 877 should have [`10.10.10.1`](http://www.cleancss.com/router-default/10.10.10.1) by default, instead. If the network settings aren't restored to their defaults, also consider you may not have yet reseted the device successfully.